# LinkedIn API auth permission for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I designed app for LinkedIn and I was used SDK: OAuth Starter Kit

I set API Key and Secret Key, and after log in I tried to post text but I couldn't because I haven't access... How to set permission???

About it: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting

Comment: I have the same issue, the only info I can get is the full name and headline. Will keep you posted when I find an answer to this issue.